Alternative QFT description
Usually QFT, in operator formalism, is described as an infinite number of harmonic oscillators, in the sense that fields are expressed as an expansion in modes and states are just the modes of each expanded field.
This expansion in modes is not fundamental as far as i know, but is something we do in order to do calculations with the fields, and it is also "problematic" for example in curved spacetimes or accelerated frames, where the decomposition is not unique.
Is there a different description of QFT which does not rely on this expansion of a field in term of normal modes?

Note that the path integral description is the same kind of description in this context, since it relies on the same Hilbert space of modes of fields that appears in the operator formalism, even if it utilizes it in a different manner to calculate and define observable quantities.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2026

Downvoting without comments is not very useful or explanatory

Describing a field as an infinite number of harmonic oscillators is another way of saying you are doing perturbation theory. For a free field, the decomposition into harmonic oscillators is exact. For an interacting field where we can use perturbation theory, we can approximate the dynamics of the field by saying that the dominant behavior is that the field acts as if it was free, with small corrections due to the interactions.
Generally, a formalism that does not rely on perturbation theory will not use a mode expansion. Unfortunately, non-perturbative quantum field theory is notoriously hard, so it's usually only possible to make progress in special cases. One example would be theories with a lot of symmetry, like conformal field theories or supersymmetric field theories, where you can use the constraints of the symmetry to infer things about observables ihe field theory without Feynman diagrams.
Also, despite your comment, the path integral is not fundamentally a harmonic oscillator description. Often, what we do is approximate the path integral as a Gaussian integral, which is perturbation theory. However, if you could calculate the path integral exactly, you would get non-perturbative answers. That's the premise behind Lattice QCD, a numerical non-perturbative approach. There are also situations where you can use the path integral analytically to gain insight into non-perturbative corrections, like instantons.

I know that mode expansion is exact for free field theories, but is there another way to describe them apart from modes? Also i thought that also in Lattice QCD we had states described by (a now discrete set of) momenta and occupation numbers of said momenta. Isn't this how LQCD is done?

@LolloBoldo I'm sure there are lots of Lattice QCD methods, so I'm sure you are right that this is something you can compute, but you can also use it to directly compute correlation functions on a lattice. As for free theories, the mode expansion gives you an exact solution, so any other solution is going to somehow be equivalent to the mode expansion, but you can represent this solution in different formalisms, like the Schrodinger functional https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional#Example:_scalar_field

Thank you very much, i didn't know about that functional representation! I will wait a few days and then if no new answers appears i will accept this

Quantum field theory on curved spacetime is a subject of active research and I don't know of any serious possibility of testing it in the near future so everything written about it should be taken with a grain of salt. A lot of the recent literature starts with an algebra of observables satisfying properties like commutation relations, evolving according to the relevant equations of motion and conditions on the set of possible states. Here are some references:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2026
https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00586
https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.11614
